# Indexing a matrix using predetermined rule

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a **72x3 double** that looks like this

```
1   1   24  
1   1   125  
2   3   17  
6   2   54  
5   1   110  
4   4   55  
6   2   200
1   4   16  
3   3   87  
...  
6   2   63
```

I would like to be able to find a value from column 3 based on the combination of values from column 1 and 2. For instance, let's call any value from column 1 **m**, value from column 2 **n**, and the corresponding value from column 3 **p**. If **m=2**, **n=3**, this will correspond to row **3** and thus **p** would be **17**. If **m=5**, **n=1**, this will give us row 5 and thus **b** would be **110**. Note that there will be cases where a set of **m** and **n** will give us two or more rows. An example would be **m=1** and **n1=1**, which should yield **24** from the first row and **125** from the second row. In this case, the output should be **[24 125]**. Similarly, a combination and **m=6** and **n= 2** would give **[54 200 63]**. **m** ranges from 1 to 6 and **n** ranges from 1 to 4. Any combination of **m** and **n** would yield no more than 4 outputs.  Could anyone help me with this indexing problem?

Thank you so much.

Alex

Comment: Could you post the expected output, just to see the way the output has to be *presented*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach assuming `A` to be the input `N x 3` array -

```
%// Find unique rows using the first two columns of A
[unqA12,~,idx] = unique(A(:,1:2),'rows')

%// Group elements from 3rd column of A based on the indexing pairs from
%// first coloumns of A and have these as a cell array
A3vals = accumarray(idx,A(:,3),[],@(x) {x})

%// Horizontally concatenate these results to present the final output
out = [num2cell(unqA12) A3vals]
```

Sample run on the given input yields the output as -

```
out = 
    [1]    [1]    [2x1 double]
    [1]    [4]    [        16]
    [2]    [3]    [        17]
    [3]    [3]    [        87]
    [4]    [4]    [        55]
    [5]    [1]    [       110]
    [6]    [2]    [3x1 double]
```

---

Or with `arrayfun` -

```
%// Find unique rows using the first two columns of A
[unqA12,~,idx] = unique(A(:,1:2),'rows')

%// Use arrayfun to do the groupings instead of accumarray this time 
out = [num2cell(unqA12) arrayfun(@(n) A(idx==n,3),1:max(idx),'Uni',0).']
```

Please note that the order of the third column elements won't be preserved in the first approach, but the second approach would do so.

Comment: Thank you, Divakar, for the prompt help. This is very helpful since these are some functions I don't usually use so it's great for learning!

Answer (score 3):

This wont be the fastest way, but another approach for beginners like me :)

```
in = [1   1   24; 
      1   1   125;
      2   3   17;
      6   2   54;  
      5   1   110;
      4   4   55;
      6   2   200;
      1   4   16;
      3   3   87];
m = input('Enter m ');
n = input('Enter n ');
Idx = all((cat(2,in(:,1) == m, in(:,2) == n)),2); 
out = in(:,3);
out1 = out(Idx);
```

**Results:**

```
Enter m 6
Enter n 2

ans =

    54
   200
----------------

Enter m 2
Enter n 3

ans =

    17
```

Comment: Thank you, Santhan! This is indeed simple enough for me to understand. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the result for a given combination of `m` and `n`, you can use just indexing:

```
m = 6;
n = 2;
result = x(x(:,1)==m & x(:,2)==n, 3).';
```

Comment: Wow, this is very efficient. Thank you, Luis!